# Insert value refer to other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, sql-insert

Here is original table A

| Currency | DM_LS | ProductID | TimeID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TWD | 1 | 26 | 559 |
| TWD | 1 | 26 | 560 |
| TWD | 1 | 27 | 561 |
| TWD | 2 | 27 | 562 |
| TWD | 2 | 28 | 563 |
| TWD | 2 | 28 | 564 |

I would like to generate serial number from table A above. So I add new column named **SerialNum**

Now I have no idea how to generate and insert the value. Value is Currency + DM_LS + ProductID + TimeID

Does it work through SQL?

**Desired Result**

| Currency | DM_LS | ProductID | TimeID | SerialNum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TWD | 1 | 26 | 559 | TWD126559 |
| TWD | 1 | 26 | 560 | TWD126560 |
| TWD | 1 | 27 | 561 | TWD127561 |
| TWD | 2 | 27 | 562 | TWD227562 |
| TWD | 2 | 28 | 563 | TWD228563 |
| TWD | 2 | 28 | 564 | TWD228564 |

Thanks so much.

Comment: Try to google `sql server concat`. You will find plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it two ways:

1. Add computed column

```sql
ALTER TABLE TABLEA ADD SerialNum AS CONCAT(Currency, DM_LS, Productid, TimeID)
```

2. Add separate column

```sql
ALTER TABLE TABLEA ADD SerialNum VARCHAR(200);

UPDATE TABLEA
SET SerialNum = CONCAT(Currency, DM_LS, Productid, TimeID)
```

Comment: Or perhaps OP just wants a `SELECT` query, bit unclear

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much.

Comment: @varen, if it answers your question, please mark it as answer, so it is helpful for others in future

Answer (score 0):

It is simply an `UPDATE` statement with concatenation on the columns.

You need to esnure each column is `CAST` to a common datatype - `VARCHAR` in this case - and then just use the format ``col1 + col2 + ...etc```